# Remove symbol from string variable

Tags: string, stata, numeric

I would like to remove the $ symbol from the observations of a Stata string variable (GDP per capita), in order to turn the variable from string to numerical. All the rows of the variable need the $ symbol to be removed.

Comment: Check out the help for the destring command.

Answer (score 0):

```
clear
input str6 problem 
"$123"
"$3456"
"$67890"
end 

destring problem, ignore($) replace 

list 

     +---------+
     | problem |
     |---------|
  1. |     123 |
  2. |    3456 |
  3. |   67890 |
     +---------+
```